# Convert a persons height from the format ft'in" to just inches

Tags: python

I have a project in my computer science class and part of it needs to know the height of a person.
I want it to ask "What is your height?(format like ft'in"): " and convert the input into just inches but I have no clue how to do this.
Any help?

Comment: There are 12 inches in 1 foot

Comment: If you search on the phrase "Python convert feet to inches", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `regex` to parse any variant of the `ft' in"` format:

```py
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"""(\d+)' *(\d+)(?:"|'')?""")
text = input("What is your height? ")
feet, inches = map(int, re.match(pattern, text).groups())
```

Here's what the regex `(\d+)' *(\d+)(?:"|'')?` does: it matches a (nonempty) group of digits on the left of an apostrophe, followed by zero or more spaces, and another group of digits, followed by an optional double-apostrophe (either `"` or `''`). As a note, since we need a literal `"` in the pattern string, it is enclosed in triple double-quotes.

The advantage of using a regex is that if your format becomes more complex later (e.g., variable number of space in between the apostrophe, possibly missing apostrophe, etc.), it's much easier to adapt since you already have everything in place. Also, you can even do some error-checking:

```py
import re

heightPattern = re.compile(r"""(\d+)' *(\d+)(?:"|'')?""")


def parseHeight() -> (int, int):
    text = input("What is your height? ")
    match = re.match(heightPattern, text)
    if not match:
        raise ValueError("Couldn't parse height")
    feet, inches = map(int, match.groups())
    return feet, inches
```

Finally, you can convert it all to inches simply by doing

```py
inches += 12*feet
```

and thus the total number of inches will be stored in `inches`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is "how do I take their textual input and turn it into numbers?"

I also have no idea what language you're using, but let's assume you're using Python, from the tag you put on the thing.

My favorite way to parse input is using regular expressions, see the [re library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Something like:

```py
import re

txt = input("What is your height? (format like ft'in\"):")
search_results = re.search("^([0-9]+)'([0-9]+)\"$")
if search_results:
  print("feet: " + int(search_results.group(1))
  print("inches: " + int(search_results.group(2))
else:
  print("You didn't format it correctly")
```

Full disclosure, I haven't tried the above code for correctness or run it. Just as a pointer in the right direction :)

Comment: Note the the question asks "convert the input into just inches".

Comment: Another has commented that there are twelve inches to the foot. I'm sure the original asker is capable of that part.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely don't need regexes to parse that. Just `split` the string!

```
text = input("Input height:")

Ft, In = text.split("'")  # "1'2\"" -> ['1', '2"']
result = int(Ft) * 12 + int(In.strip()[:-1])  # get rid of the trailing double quote with `[:-1]`

print(f'You are {result} inches tall')
```

Comment: What about the trailing `"` at the end of the inches? You are forgetting about that.

Comment: @djhaskin987, oops, fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get as a string and split to feet and inches

```
text = input("Enter your height: ") # Format should be <int>"<int>'
feet = int(text.split("\"")[0])
inch = int(text.split("\"")[1].split("'")[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple Python3 code **without** regex:

```
h = input('Enter height in ft\'in": ')  # ask for input
h_split = h.split('\'')  # break string into 2 parts where single quote occurs
ft, inch = (h_split[0], h_split[1].split('"')[0])  # extract inches in a similar way
ft = int(ft)  # convert feet to integer
inch = int(inch)  # convert inches to integer
height = ft*12 + inch  # convert feet to inches and add inches
print(f'Height in inches: {height}')  # For Python2 use print 'Height in inches: ' + str(height)
```

Good luck!